# Замена символа в произвольном тексте

Tags: c++

По условиям лабораторной работы **нельзя** использовать методы класса string. Необходимо использовать функции библиотеки string.h!

Задача: в произвольном тексте в словах с указанными номерами заменить заданную букву на другую заданную букву пользователем.
Есть два вопроса:
1)как правильно искать слово по номеру(пример кода, если можно)?
2)как "перешагивать" слова, номера которых не заданы? *в коде есть блок, который делает этот шаг, но не уверен в правильности*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char text[100],*wbeg, * wend, delim[] = " ;:,.?!"; 
    do { cout << "Text: "; cin.getline(text, 100);} while (strlen(text) == 0);
    int n_delim = strspn(text, delim); // кол-ство разделителей
    wbeg = text + n_delim; // указатель на начало слова
    wend = text + strlen(text); // указатель на конец слова
    n_delim = strcspn(wbeg, delim); 
    cout << "Quantity of words to change = "; int count_w;  cin >> count_w;
    int* nums_w = new int[count_w]; // массив номеров слов
    for (int i = 0; i < count_w; i++)
    {
        cout << "Numbers of words: "; cin >> nums_w[i];// ввод номеров слов для обработки
        int count = 1;
        while ((wbeg + n_delim <= wend) && (n_delim != 0))
        {
            if (count == nums_w[i]) 
            {
                cout << "Symbol, that should be changed: "; char ch1; cin >> ch1; 
                char* pos_s = strchr(wbeg, ch1); 
                if (*pos_s == 0) { cout << "No symbol!"; }
                else if (pos_s != 0 && wbeg + n_delim < pos_s) 
                {
                    cout << "\nSymbol to change one: "; char ch2; cin >> ch2;
                    *pos_s = ch2;
                    cout << text;
                }
            }
            else 
            { 
                count++;
                memmove(wbeg, wbeg + n_delim, strlen(wbeg + n_delim) + 1);
                wbeg = wbeg + n_delim;
                n_delim = strspn(wbeg, delim);
                wbeg = wbeg + n_delim;
                n_delim = strcspn(wbeg, delim);
                wend = text + strlen(text);
                cout << text;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[]nums_w;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как искать слово - следует сначала дать определения слова, а исходя из определения их и искать. И что за вопрос то такой: как перешагивать - как это вообще понимать?

Comment: Я бы сделал копию и в ней с помощью `strtok` искал слова. А потом использовал их смещение от начала. Это если исходить из разделителей. У вас, простите уж, понять, что вы хотели, у меня не получается.